# CSharp cannot retrieve correct data from datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Good Morning,
I'm trying to get a string value from a DataGridView cell, but I cannot store this into a variable and I don't know why it's not storing it.
I have a `DataGridView` filled by a dynamic `DataTable` (dynamic because I fill that with data stored in a DB)

So, I've tried to capture the `SelectionChanged` and then I've done something like this:

```
public string selectedItemIndex = String.empty;
```

...

```
foreach (var row in DataGridView.SelectedCelss)
{
   DataRowView view = row.Item as DataRowView;
   if (view != null)
   {
      selectedItemIndex = view.row[0] as string;
      //selectedItemIndex = view.row["INDEX"] as string; 
   }
}
```

if I debug the application I get something like this:

```
selectedItemIndex = view.row[0] as string; --> DataRow.this[int].get()= 168 //exactly what I'm expecting
```

but if I look at the public declared variable, I get this:

```
public string SelectedItemIndex; --> SelectedItemIndex = null
```

I don't know what to do, I need the variable to be public so I can retrieve that also in other classes. There's some other method?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Better use a ToString call than to rely on a cast. And of course the Index is just a number..

Comment: Mmmmm, I fell so dumb... Just changed from as string to .ToString() and it worked. Thank you